# PostgreSQL - Insert script for date dimension table miscalculates year value for the first and the last few days of the year

Tags: postgresql

I am using [this](https://gist.github.com/duffn/38449526e00abb47f4ec292f0491313d) script to create and populate a partly localized (for Turkish) date dimension table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dim_date
(
    dim_date_id            INT        NOT NULL,
    date_actual            DATE       NOT NULL,
    epoch                  BIGINT     NOT NULL,
    day_suffix             VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    day_name               VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    day_name_tr            VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    day_of_week            INT        NOT NULL,
    day_of_month           INT        NOT NULL,
    day_of_quarter         INT        NOT NULL,
    day_of_year            INT        NOT NULL,
    week_of_month          INT        NOT NULL,
    week_of_year           INT        NOT NULL,
    week_of_year_iso       CHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
    month_actual           INT        NOT NULL,
    month_name             VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    month_name_tr          VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    month_name_abbreviated CHAR(3)    NOT NULL,
    quarter_actual         INT        NOT NULL,
    quarter_name           VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    year_actual            INT        NOT NULL,
    first_day_of_week      DATE       NOT NULL,
    last_day_of_week       DATE       NOT NULL,
    first_day_of_month     DATE       NOT NULL,
    last_day_of_month      DATE       NOT NULL,
    first_day_of_quarter   DATE       NOT NULL,
    last_day_of_quarter    DATE       NOT NULL,
    first_day_of_year      DATE       NOT NULL,
    last_day_of_year       DATE       NOT NULL,
    mmyyyy                 CHAR(6)    NOT NULL,
    mmddyyyy               CHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
    weekend_indr           BOOLEAN    NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE dim_date ADD CONSTRAINT d_date_dim_date_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (dim_date_id);
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY d_date_date_actual_idx ON dim_date(date_actual);


set LC_TIME to 'tr_TR.UTF-8';

COMMIT;
INSERT INTO dim_date
SELECT TO_CHAR(datum, 'yyyymmdd')::INT AS dim_date_id,
       datum AS date_actual,
       EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM datum) AS epoch,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'fmDDth') AS day_suffix,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'Day') AS day_name,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'TMDay') AS day_name_tr,
       EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM datum) AS day_of_week,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM datum) AS day_of_month,
       datum - DATE_TRUNC('quarter', datum)::DATE + 1 AS day_of_quarter,
       EXTRACT(DOY FROM datum) AS day_of_year,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'W')::INT AS week_of_month,
       EXTRACT(WEEK FROM datum) AS week_of_year,
       EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM datum) || TO_CHAR(datum, '"-W"IW-') || EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM datum) AS week_of_year_iso,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datum) AS month_actual,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'Month') AS month_name,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'TMMonth') AS month_name_tr,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'Mon') AS month_name_abbreviated,
       EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM datum) AS quarter_actual,
       CASE
           WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM datum) = 1 THEN 'First'
           WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM datum) = 2 THEN 'Second'
           WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM datum) = 3 THEN 'Third'
           WHEN EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM datum) = 4 THEN 'Fourth'
           END AS quarter_name,
       EXTRACT(ISOYEAR FROM datum) AS year_actual,
       datum + (1 - EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM datum))::INT AS first_day_of_week,
       datum + (7 - EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM datum))::INT AS last_day_of_week,
       datum + (1 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM datum))::INT AS first_day_of_month,
       (DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', datum) + INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::DATE AS last_day_of_month,
       DATE_TRUNC('quarter', datum)::DATE AS first_day_of_quarter,
       (DATE_TRUNC('quarter', datum) + INTERVAL '3 MONTH - 1 day')::DATE AS last_day_of_quarter,
       TO_DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datum) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS first_day_of_year,
       TO_DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datum) || '-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS last_day_of_year,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'mmyyyy') AS mmyyyy,
       TO_CHAR(datum, 'mmddyyyy') AS mmddyyyy,
       CASE
           WHEN EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM datum) IN (6, 7) THEN TRUE
           ELSE FALSE
           END AS weekend_indr
FROM (SELECT '1970-01-01'::DATE + SEQUENCE.DAY AS datum
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 29219) AS SEQUENCE (DAY)
      GROUP BY SEQUENCE.DAY) DQ
ORDER BY 1;
COMMIT;
```

It works great for the most part except the first and the last few days of the year. For these days, `year_actual` are miscalculated, and I am having trouble figuring out why. What is the root cause of this strange behaviour?

```sql
SELECT year_actual, date_actual
FROM dim_date
WHERE year_actual <> EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_actual);
```

| year_actual | date_actual |
| --- | --- |
| 2020 | 2019-12-30 |
| 2020 | 2019-12-31 |
| 2020 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2020 | 2021-01-02 |
| 2020 | 2021-01-03 |

Comment: Why not let generate dates directly: `from generate(date '1970-01-01', current_date, interval '1 day')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO year only has a meaning together with an ISO **week** because the first ISO week of a year could start in the previous year.

So `year_actual` should be generated using

```
extract(year from ...) as year_actual
```

The expression to generate the `week_of_year_iso` column can be simplified to:

```
to_char(datum, 'iyyy-iw') as week_of_year_iso
```